# Show the difference of lines between two files

Tags: emacs, elisp

How to implement a functionality in emacs to show the difference of contents between two files opened in two buffers?
Kind of like revdiff when using mercurial.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Emacs has [`ediff`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/ediff.html), which can diff two files.  To use it, just do `M-x ediff`, and specify the two files you want to diff.

Answer (score 3):

BTW, if you want to see the differences between two blocks of text in the same buffer, you can do it as follows:
- make sure smerge-mode is loaded (e.g. `M-x load-library RET smerge-mode RET`).
- go to the beginning of the first bloc, `C-SPC`
- go the beginning of the second bloc, `C-SPC`
- go to the end of the second bloc, `M-x smerge-makeup-conflict RET`
- then you can use `C-c ^ R` or `C-c ^ =` to view the differences.
Note that this works better if the two blocs are pretty much consecutive.

Answer (score 1):

`M-x diff` does that.

See the docs for more: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Comparing-Files.html

Answer (score 1):

I also found that compare-windows does an amazing job cycling through differences in opened buffers.